# Php array transformation and combination

Tags: php, arrays

So I have array like this one

```
[
    'custid' => [
        'customer_number_1' => '20098374',
        'customer_number_8' => '20098037',
        'customer_number_15' => '20098297'
    ],
    'destid' => [
        'destination_numbers_1' => [
            (int) 0 => '20024838',
            (int) 1 => '20041339'
        ],
        'destination_numbers_8' => [
            (int) 0 => '20008293'
        ],
        'destination_numbers_15' => [
            (int) 0 => '20016969',
            (int) 1 => '20022919',
            (int) 2 => '20025815',
            (int) 3 => '20026005',
            (int) 4 => '20027083',
            (int) 5 => '20045497'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Goal is to merge cust id with destid in pairs and should look like so

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 1,
        'sap_customer_id' => '20098374',
        'sap_destination_id' => '20024838'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 1,
        'sap_customer_id' => '20098374',
        'sap_destination_id' => '20041339',
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 1,
        'sap_customer_id' => '20098037',
        'sap_destination_id' => '20008293,
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 1,
        'sap_customer_id' => '20098297'
        'sap_destination_id' => '20016969',
    ],
...
```

I have tried with code below, but I am getting destination_id number as array and duplicated customer numbers. Also I have tried with array walk but result is same.

```
$data = [];
        foreach ($sap_data['custid'] as $custid) {
          foreach ($sap_data['destid'] as $destid) {
            $data[] = [
              'user_id' => 1,
              'sap_customer_id' => $custid,
              'sap_destination_id' => $destid
            ];
          }
        }
```

Thx for helping!

Comment: Should 'user_id' always be 1 in the result? Just double checking..

Comment: No, but it will be fix number sent from Form view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make inner loop in other way

```
foreach($sap_data['custid'] as $k => $custid) {
   // Make destination key
   $dkey = str_replace('customer_number', 'destination_numbers', $k);
   // And get array, for example, destination_numbers_1 for customer_number_1
   foreach ($sap_data['destid'][$dkey] as $destid) {
     $data[] = [
              'user_id' => 1,
              'sap_customer_id' => $custid,
              'sap_destination_id' => $destid
            ];
   }
}
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/791187)**